# How to reduce font size of the header/footer in Firefox print jobs?

Tags: firefox, printing

When printing from Firefox, the font size of headers/footers (Title, URL, Page, Date) is noticeably larger in Ubuntu when compared to Windows. The larger font means less of the Title and URL headers show on the page. And it also takes away space from the page's main content.

Is there a way to make the font smaller? Changing the "Content" preferences in Firefox to a smaller font size has no effect on the headers and footers. But regardless, I only want to reduce the font size of the headers/footers, not the page's main content.

Answer (score 1):

It's not configurable right now, though it would be possible to improve Firefox to make it configurable.

It looks like [this is where that font is configured](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/generic/nsSimplePageSequence.cpp?rev=1e3af440ce23&mark=127-128#116), in the Mozilla source code.  As you can see, it's simply set to be Serif 10pt right now.